# HSQLDB memory consumption

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

If more than 1 million rows of data are accumulated in the database, approximately 2 GB of memory is required by the getConnection() when the DB connection is made.

Why do I need a lot of memory , and wondering , wondering if there is a way to reduce the amount of memory required .

Comment: This question is very unclear, what database are you using what language are you writing code in? Even if those things were known, this question would be too broad. Narrow down the scope and ask a specific question based on verifiable, reproducible conditions.

Comment: It is tagged HSQLDB, so the database is clear .

Answer (score 4):

If you use the default table type in HSQLDB, all data is kept in memory for very fast access.

For large databases, you should use CREATE CACHED TABLE to store the data mostly on hard disk. You can convert your existing table with

```
 SET TABLE mytablename TYPE CACHED
```